# Why Jenkins mounts a temporary volume in addition to the workspace?

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline

I am using `gulp` to run my js app on the docker container from an image built using a dockerfile.
I am an advanced beginner :) in Jenkins.

dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.11.0-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git curl python py-pip bzip2 alpine-sdk && \
  pip install --upgrade awscli && \
  rm -rf /tmp/* /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apk/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

ADD . /usr/src/app/.
RUN chmod -R 777 /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

jenkinsFile - I am using sequential stages. The first stage is Initialize where I am setting up the docker container. The docker image is hosted internally, I am pulling that down and running the shell commands. To keep it simple I am adding only the relevant stages here.

```
 pipeline {
        agent none
        options {
            timeout(time: timeoutSeconds, unit: 'SECONDS')
            disableConcurrentBuilds()
        }
 stage('Initialize') {
                agent {
                    docker {
                        image 'js-docker-image'
                        registryUrl 'https://my-artifactory-url'
                        registryCredentialsId artifactoryCredentialsId
                        args '-u root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
                        label 'docker'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Install Dependencies') {
                        steps {
                            script {
                                def command = '''
                                    npm install
                                    '''
                                sh command
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Build') {
                        steps {
                            script {
                                def command = '''
                                    ./node_modules/.bin/gulp build_only
                                   '''
                                sh command
                            }
                        }
                    }
...
```

Here are the relevant parts in the build output. I have removed some sensitive info.

```
...
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Initialize)
[Pipeline] node
Running on slave06 in /opt/jenkins/slave06/workspace/ntegrate-playground-573
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] checkout
...
$ docker run -t -d -u 133733063:133693953 -u root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -w /opt/jenkins/slave06/workspace/ntegrate-playground-573 -v /opt/jenkins/slave06/workspace/ntegrate-playground-573:/opt/jenkins/slave06/workspace/ntegrate-playground-573:rw,z -v /opt/jenkins/slave06/workspace/ntegrate-playground-573@tmp:/opt/jenkins/slave06/workspace/ntegrate-playground-573@tmp:rw,z -e ********  docker-internal-registry/js-docker-image:latest cat
...
...
$ docker top f6cddf731de8cd63c37e12462f1041db2f4a14486ad98e00dbb81d210711bc63
+ npm install
npm WARN jsdom@15.2.1 requires a peer of canvas@^2.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

audited 901232 packages in 20.046s
found 16 vulnerabilities (4 low, 1 moderate, 11 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ ./node_modules/.bin/gulp build_only
/opt/jenkins/slave06/workspace/ntegrate-playground-573@tmp/durable-8c5396a6/script.sh: line 1: ./node_modules/.bin/gulp: not found
```

Questions

1. Why is Jenkins trying to attach a new volume with @tmp?
2. What is durable-8c5396a6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) Why is Jenkins trying to attach a new volume with @tmp?**

the `@tmp` is used to place temp artifacts, like the Shell scriptin `sh`, jenkins will
create a `.sh` file which includes the script of `sh`, then execute this `.sh` file.

Because this `.sh` file is not part of your source code, just temp file generated during stages running.

You can think of the files in `@tmp` are managed by Jenkins, not by user. User can't control it.  It's a part of Jenkins pipeline design.

For source code, build/package artifact managed by use, they are not been placed in the `@tmp`, but in job workspace folder, in your case is `/opt/jenkins/slave06/workspace/ntegrate-playground-573`, which without the `@tmp`.

**2) What is durable-8c5396a6?**

Jenkins generated `.sh` file for each `sh` with same name `script.sh`.
In case there are more than one `sh` in your Jenkinsfile, jenkins put `script.sh` in different folder to avoid it for previous `sh` overwriten by next `sh`

**To debug your issue**, add two cmds `pwd` and `ls -l` before `./node_modules/.bin/gulp build_only`. With that to check your current work dir and which files & folders under current work dir.

The most possible failure reason is you are in wrong work dir, secondly it's `gulp` is not added into project dependencies.

Comment: Yes, those commands helped me. I am on the right folder. `gulp` is also defined as a dev dependency on my package.json, yet jenkins shell complains that gulp is not found in the path. When I manually browse through the workspaces UI, I see the file, but with a little red icon underneath. Like the file is being cleaned up before it is needed. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check you  define `cleanup` in `post` in Jenkinsfile?  Or there is a disk clean program run regularly to release space.  Check the free disk if you can,  try run the job again in different time to avoid the regular clean time slot.

Comment: This is very similar (or maybe even exactly the same) problem I am facing. previous stage builds an executable and places somewhere in the workspace and the next stage tries to execute that. Using the same declarative pipeline structure. Stages containing a series of stages. That executable created in the previous stage is not available to the `sh` step in the following stage. I read this post/answer but wasn't sure what the resolution was...