# Jenkins build on temp "@" directory

Tags: linux, jenkins, centos

I'm having some issues with Jenkins where my job keeps building under a temp directory example build_job_name@#.

I tried deleting all of the folders with that were created in the Workspace/, deleted all of the past builds under Jobs/, added the delete workspace before and after the job runs and even recreated the job from scratch.

The name of the job is important so I need to get build_job_name to stop building as build_job_name@#.

Does anyone know what needs to be done to stop it from building temp folders?

Comment: you can get more info of the @tmp folder from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59220020/why-jenkins-mounts-a-temporary-volume-in-addition-to-the-workspace/59222111#59222111.  It's managed by Jenkins, you can't control it.

Comment: Thanks @yong, the issue resolved itself after a server restart. Fortunately the server was due for maintenance so I had the opportunity to knock both issues off the list.