# Jenkins pipeline job executing commands in tmp folder

Tags: android, macos, jenkins, pipeline, emulation

### MacOS Monterey version 12.4

I'm trying to run a simple pipeline script on my jenkins job

```
   pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh('emulator -list-avds')
            }
        }
    }
```

But it throws an error:

```
/Users/<my_username>/.jenkins/workspace/<my_job_name>@tmp/durable-22217e91/script.sh: line 1: emulator: command not found
```

My question is: why is it executing commands in the tmp folder? Anything "emulator" related does work when I run commands via terminal.

Following this answer, I've confirmed I'm in the correct dir
[Why Jenkins mounts a temporary volume in addition to the workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59220020/why-jenkins-mounts-a-temporary-volume-in-addition-to-the-workspace/59222111#59222111)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because the emulator executable is not set in the `PATH`. Try something like the below.

Try setting your PATH variable to add emulator executable.

```
environment {
   PATH = "/PATH_EMULATOR/bin:${env.PATH}"
}
```

or something like the below.

```
  withEnv(["PATH+EMULATOR=/PATH_EMULATOR/bin"]) {
    sh('emulator -list-avds')
  }
```

or you can also use the full qualified path to the executable

```
sh('/PATH_TO_EMULATOR/bin/emulator -list-avds')
```

Comment: Hi, I do have my PATH variable set up and this is a part of it: export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator

Comment: Where have you set this? If you echo $PATH before the `sh` step do you see the emulator path set?

Comment: getting this: /Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/bin64:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: If you execute this way `sh('/PATH_TO_EMULATOR/bin/emulator -list-avds')` does it work?

Comment: It didn't but I've added the path to my pipeline script and now it's working fine! Not sure why it doesn't recognise PATH set up in my .zshrc file though